# SSIS Error: Violation of primary key constraint. cannot insert duplicate key in object

Tags: sql-server, ssis, database-administration, ssis-2012

I'm working with a team to resolve a SSIS package failure. The package contains four Sequence container and each container have some set of sql tasks which truncate a target table and insert data from a source to target. At times package fails with error: Violation of primary key constraint. cannot insert duplicate key in object even though there is no violation as the table is empty when we start the load. Please provide suggestions on how to troubleshoot the issue

Note: Source and destination have some difference in structure. Source tables containd PK on only one int column. Destination table contains one more additional PK which is a default value. I dont understand why we need a constrant on a default column value.

Comment: Without looking at your table definitions from both tables or being able to see the package it's really hard to give you any help. However the issue is as it says. It found a duplicate row and SQL server threw an error as a result. You can either redirect the error row to a file or check the run log to determine the value that failed.

Comment: @Zane Updated the question with the requested details

Comment: I sounds like you need to better understand your data structure. Also if you look at the package error it should show you exactly which value is causing the issue.

Comment: Sorry guys! Development team has done horrible logging set up. The issue is with the test environment pointing to QA and they both run at the same time. But their email logging tells PROD package failed. :( which made my day crazy!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like even though the target table is empty when you run the SSIS package, the rows you're inserting themselves contain duplicate data. (i.e. if your PK is called [ID], you're trying to insert more than one of the same [ID] into the table)

Comment: But how come my source with Primary Key have duplicates?

Comment: I'm sure it doesn't. You'll need to step through the package you're troubleshooting to see what is happening. The Data Viewer can be useful for that. But if you're getting a primary key violation and there's no data in there, you're definitely trying to insert duplicates with the package.

Comment: In the package it's just loading data from table to table direclty with table or view fast load in SSIS data access mode. No queries involved.